# Is djblets still useful with Django 1.2?

Tags: django

I've just came around `dbjlets` which was released in 2008. It adds many useful functions, but it's also a big lumb of code.

Does it still make sense to use djblets in 2010, or have better alternatives emerged? I also suspect some features have been merged into Django.

I'm particulary interested in:

- `auth` - I guess `django-registration` addresses this?
- `datagrid`
- `rooturl` - allow easy deployment in a subfolder
- `decorators` - easier writing of blocktags, etc..
- `JSONField` - store random data.
- `siteconfig` - overlay settings.py with database settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Djblets is still actively developed, I think it still has purpose:)

Link to the current repository: http://github.com/djblets/djblets

- `auth`: `django-registration` might be better for this, it depends on your needs, I suppose.
- `datagrid`: I don't know a single other decent datagrid app for Django, it doesn't mean there are none. But I don't know them ;)
- `rooturl`: I am not sure if that's really that useful. I don't see much advantage in that compared to the normal URL system.
- `decorators`: writing tags in Django is still a lot of work, but this makes it quite easy. Definitely worth it. Although Django has quite a few similar shortcuts these days.
- `JSONField`: it can definitely be handy, but a lot of the times it's the wrong solution ;)
- `siteconfig`: I believe that there are several projects that focus on this specifically, just find one that you like (or think of your own structure, which is what I did).

All in all it comes down to, do you find the extensions useful. Personally I think that the `datagrid` and the `decorators` are the most useful parts.

But instead of using `decorators` to make writing tags easier you could also try `Jinja2` as a template parser which allows multiple and named arguments for filters. Or simply calling functions directly. That way you rarely need template tags.

Comment: Thanks! I've fount a substitute for siteconfig at http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/live-setting/